# Implicit casting in function arguments, what happens inside this one?

Tags: c, casting

Look I learned that basic types to function are promoted to int and float is promoted to double, but wait, if I pass a char to a function like:

`char character;
my_func (character)`

void my_func (char buffer)

Every time that I refer to buffer  is it a int??? If yes, wait, what about all that code that I wrote refering buffer as char? Is it doing cast from int to char?
What about pointers, arrays and structs enum unions etc?
I'm very afraid about that because I guess that using another types instead int is a error because everything that I did it will be converted to int. right?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: No. Casting happens when you assign one type to another. There is no int here. Buffer is a char, and always shall be a char. You have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promotion of basic types in a function call is only relevant if you're using old-style code with no prototypes (if your compiler supports that) or using `...` varargs functions.  In you case you have a prototype, and it matches, so there's no conversion or promotion.

In any case, promotion only applies to numeric types -- it does not apply to pointers, arrays, structs, or unions.

Comment: YES, OMG I FORGOT THE WORD ABSENCE, LOOK #Since an argument of a function call is an expression, type conversion also takes place when arguments are passed to functions. In the ABSENCE of a function prototype, char and short become int, and float becomes double. This is why we have declared function arguments to be int and double even when the function is called with char and float. # K&R C BOOK, thanks a lot guy.